# An error occurred while constructing a 3D vector class

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, rvalue, lvalue

I'm debugging a 3D vector code, but I get the following error

```bash
/usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g /home/fangrui/vectorFEM/vectorFEM/main.cpp -o /home/fangrui/vectorFEM/vectorFEM/main
In file included from /home/fangrui/vectorFEM/vectorFEM/constant.h:6:0,
                 from /home/fangrui/vectorFEM/vectorFEM/mesh.h:2,
                 from /home/fangrui/vectorFEM/vectorFEM/edgenedelec.h:2,
                 from /home/fangrui/vectorFEM/vectorFEM/main.cpp:1:
/home/fangrui/vectorFEM/vectorFEM/cvector3D.h: In function ‘cvector operator*(double, cvector)’:
/home/fangrui/vectorFEM/vectorFEM/cvector3D.h:39:10: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘cvector&’ to an rvalue of type ‘cvector’
   return cvector(x1*x2.x, x1*x2.y, x1*x2.z); 
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
```

It's a problem in `cvector3D.h` file, but I don't understand this bug and what kind of changes should be made. In addition to the error above, there is also a warning about `friend`:

```cpp
class "cvector" has no suitable copy constructorC/C++(334)
```

here is the original code for `cvector3D.h`

```cpp
# ifndef CVECTOR3D_H
# define CVECTOR3D_H

#include<cmath>
#include<ostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

/*A three-dimensional real vector class is defined to facilitate numerical calculations*/
class cvector
{
public:
    double x, y, z;
    //Construct function
    cvector(double _x, double _y, double _z){ x = _x; y = _y; z = _z; } 
    //Copy the constructor
    cvector(cvector &pt){ x = pt.x; y = pt.y; z = pt.z; }
    cvector(){ x = 0; y = 0; z = 0; }
    ~cvector(){};

    //Operator overloading
    cvector operator +();
    cvector operator -();                   //The vector is negated

    friend  ostream  &operator<<(ostream &os, const cvector &x1);

    cvector operator +(cvector x1);
    cvector operator -(cvector x1);
    cvector operator *(double x1);
    cvector operator /(double x1);
    cvector &operator =(cvector x1);
    cvector &operator +=(cvector x1);
    cvector &operator -=(cvector x1);
    cvector &operator *=(double x1);
    cvector &operator /=(double x1);
    int operator ==(cvector x1);
    int operator !=(cvector x1);
    friend cvector operator *(double x1, cvector x2) {
        return cvector(x1*x2.x, x1*x2.y, x1*x2.z); 
    }
    //Member functions
    double  dist(cvector x1);                       
    cvector unit();                               
    double  norm();                           
    friend cvector cross(cvector x1, cvector x2)       
    {
        return cvector(x1.y*x2.z - x1.z*x2.y, x1.z*x2.x - x1.x*x2.z, x1.x*x2.y - x1.y*x2.x);
    }
    friend double dot(cvector x1, cvector x2)      
    {
        return (x1.x*x2.x + x1.y*x2.y + x1.z*x2.z);
    }
} ;

# endif
```

Comment: copy constructor should be `cvector(const cvector&)`

Comment: Add `const` to all non-mutating member functions such as `cvector operator +(cvector x1) const` and `double  dist(cvector x1) const`.

Comment: In C++ you cannot ignore `const`.

Comment: There is no need for a user-defined copy constructor in `cvector`.  All you're doing by supplying one is have a way to introduce bugs -- what if you introduce another member variable, and you forgot to copy it in your user-defined constructor?.  All of the members are `double`, thus the class all by itself is safely-copyable, i.e the default copy constructor generated by the compiler is perfectly fine, works correctly, and will not introduce bugs.  Bottom line -- remove the copy constructor until you actually need to add one.

Comment: `friend cvector cross(cvector x1, cvector x2)` -- If you are used to Python, Java, C# or similar languages, this does **not** do what you think it does when it comes to C++.  Those parameters do not create references to the passed-in `cvector` -- instead, temporary copies are made.  If you want references in C++, you must explicitly make it known by using the reference operator `&`.  This is one big mistake that programmers make when coming from other languages, and that is to think that parameter passing works the same way as those other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The `cvector` copy constructor is malformed.**

The correct form is `cvector(const cvector& cvec)`.

**Long Description:**

When the friend function

```
friend cvector operator *(double x1, cvector x2) {
        return cvector(x1*x2.x, x1*x2.y, x1*x2.z); 
    }
```

is called the construnctor of `cvector` is called.
Immediatly after the constructed object is returned by copy, so the copy constructor is called, but the lvalue just created of type `cvector&`, that is `non-const` cannot be converted to an rvalue of type `cvector`.

This because a non-const reference parameter, such as for example an `int&,` can only refer to an "lvalue," which is a named variable.

In this case the object created is not a named variable.

Comment: The elephant in the room is that there is no need for a user-defined copy constructor to being with.

Comment: yes, the default construct can be enough